# Universal App roaming data not synchronized between devices

Tags: windows, windows-runtime, win-universal-app, roaming

I'm writing out a data file into the RoamingFolder that is not larger than 10KB after the app is closed (suspended). The app runs on the dev desktop and the Surface 2, both of which are signed on to the same Microsoft Account. But the roaming data is not synchronized no matter how long I wait (I even left for lunch and came back 40 minutes later to no avail).

Both apps are verified to be closed, so there are no active file handles. Both devices will write the data into the Roaming Folder themselves if the app is opened/closed on each. And both devices sync data of other apps from the Windows Store.

The guidelines (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465094.aspx) state that sync is triggered by locking the device. This does not seem to trigger the sync either.

Comment: Does your program close the handle of the file on RoamingFolder before it be suspended? If suspended program keeps the handle opened, that file never be roaming. Try to quit the first (writing) program completely before starting the second (reading) program.

Comment: Yes, all files handles are closed. The app disappears from the process list.

Comment: After the process which write files quited, can other process read the file on RoamingFolder?  I　doubt that process which write process keeps handler opened in suspended status.

Comment: Have you tried the roaming monitor? http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3ccf8c24-5e72-4ba0-b3e9-d822ca345fd0

Comment: @JeffSanders-MSFT It's for VS2012 only.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, 
make sure your **app is associated with the store**.

For other details check out [this](https://mtaulty.com/2014/04/29/m_15202/) blog.

Comment: The link is broken... can you explain the solution please?

Comment: @Cabuxa.Mapache : Fixed the linked.